# Is it there any way to detect payloads generated by veil framework

Tags: malware, penetration-test, hardening

While pentesting, I used to generate a malicious payloads using the [veil framework](https://github.com/Veil-Framework/Veil-Evasion). The generated payload bypasses antivirus & infects the target system.

Is there any way to detect veil payloads in a victim machine? How can I secure my system from malicious payloads generated by veil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veil is actually not too good at creating payloads that evade AV. I've created numerous payloads and they're all detected upon upload to Virus Total.

You could try the following:

- Write a script to create a hash checksum of every file on a fresh, untainted install of your OS
- Run the same script on your machine (with the suspect Veil infected files)
- Compare the hashes
- Any hashes that don't match up, replace the files with the untainted versions

Alternatively and a more safer way to go would be to wipe your system and start from scratch.

Comment: I thought you weren't supposed to upload to VirusTotal?

Comment: Correct, if you're using proper payloads (e.g. shellter). For proper payloads it's always best to check the hash against Virus Total using the API. NanoAV seems to pick up all of the Veil based payloads too.